# Aurelia - cant get asp net core with typescript skeeton to work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, installation, aurelia

I am trying to get aurelia up and running using a skeleton project from github. See link https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation.

I am using the skeleton targeting ASP.NET Core using typescript named "skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore".

I download the skeleton project and afterwards open it in visual studio 2017 with latest update.

When i build the project i get 70 errors, mainly typescript errors. All of the errors looks similar to this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'by'.  skeleton (tsconfig project) D:\skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore\src\skeleton\test\e2e\src\skeleton.po.ts  12  Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'aurelia-router'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) D:\skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore\src\skeleton\src\app.ts   1   Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS6059  File 'D:/skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore/src/skeleton/test/unit/users.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'D:/skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.  skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active

I am new to typescript and completely new to aurelia and ASP.NET Core.

Am i missing something here or is the skeleton project simply broken?

**UPDATE:**

It seems to have something to do with typescript since i can get the ASP.NET Core project to work with esnext using the skeleton project "skeleton-esnext-aspnetcore". Here i simple downloaded the project and ran it - nothing else. And i guess the typescript project should be like that too. So to me  it looks like the skeleton project "skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore" might not work?

Comment: VS2017 might not have installed all dependencies. Try running `npm install` and `dotnet restore` in the console.

Comment: I did a dotnet restore and an npm install. the npm install failed with "'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command". I am trying to investigate that one. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Make sure you're using an up to date version of node and npm

Comment: I have version 5.0.3 of npm, it should be pretty new.

Comment: I have also done an "jspm install" command.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [configuration](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore/src/skeleton) steps.

Please make sure you are having proper environment setup.

First, there are a set of prerequisites you will need whether or not you are using Visual Studio. Make sure to install these prerequisites before proceeding.

`NodeJS >=4.0.0` This provides the platform on which the build tooling runs. This may be downloaded and installed from the NodeJS website.

`NPM >=3.0.0` This is installed with NodeJS, but if you install a 4.x version of NodeJS, you may have to update this.

`jspm`, `gulp`, and `typings`. These three tools may be installed by running `npm install -g jspm` gulp typings from a command line after installing NodeJS and NPM

**Additional Prerequisites:**

- Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3
- [ASP.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows#windows) must be downloaded and installed. The directions for
  doing this are [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows).

You can find step by step process from below link:
https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore/src/skeleton